# Mysql select unique value

Tags: mysql, select, join

I have a mysql table with the following structure:

```
id_category | id_product
     1           1
     15          1
     28          1
     5           2
     15          2
     1           2
     13          3
     4           3
```

I would like to make a query that I will use inside an "AND" clause of a JOIN structure which selects the products that have e.g. the id_category 1 and 15 and the output to be the id of the product but only once:

```
id_product
   1     
   2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use like this ;

```
select  distinct(id_product) from table_name
where id_category=1 or id_category=15
group by id_product;
```

Here is [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e81bf/6) example

```
EDIT:
```

I understand what you mean.. I can give two example using join and where clause;

Lets look at first example;

```
SELECT `settings`.*, `character_settings`.`value`
FROM (`settings`)
LEFT JOIN `character_settings` 
ON `character_settings`.`setting_id` = `settings`.`id`
WHERE `character_settings`.`character_id` = '1'
```

As you see in the first example, `character_id` is filtering with where clause however, The `where clause` is filtering away rows where the `left join` doesn't succeed. So we need to do this in join with `AND` Move it to the join:

```
SELECT  `settings`.*, `character_settings`.`value`
FROM    `settings`
LEFT JOIN 
       `character_settings` 
ON     `character_settings`.`setting_id` = `settings`.`id`
        AND `character_settings`.`character_id` = '1'
```

So in order to use `WHERE` clause in join, use `AND` operator in `JOIN`. Hope this is helpful to solve your question.

EDIT2 :

In your problem it possible that you need to use `OR` not `AND`

Comment: Thank you that was really helpful. The problem now is that I need that to include it inside an "AND" clause of a JOIN. How can I achieve that?

Comment: @DimitriosMarkopoulos I didnt understand what you mean. Give an example so that I can write complete query

Comment: Yes, sorry for my bad english. here is the script: http://pastie.org/pastes/10107359

Comment: @DimitriosMarkopoulos see my last edit. I hope this will be useful for your problem.

Comment: So if I understood correctly, you replaced WHERE with AND in the second case. Thanks, I ll try it..

Comment: @DimitriosMarkopoulos yes you are correct.. maybe you should use OR in your problem..

Answer (score 1):

You may do as

```
select 
id_product from table_name
where id_category in (1,15)
group by id_product 
having count(*) = 2
```

Comment: Can I put this select inside and "AND" clause?

Comment: When you do where with `and` this will check against each row and you can never have both the conditions satisfying for single row, hence we have this approach using `group by` and `having`

Comment: So shall I write something like this: AND (id_category in (1,15) group by id_product having count(*) = 2)" ?

Comment: Show me the complete query that you are trying.

Comment: Then update the question and add into the question. Without seeing the query its difficult to give any advice

Comment: The query looks correct and you have added the in condition correctly AND product_shop.visibility IN ("both", "catalog")`, however you will need a having clause after the `group by` as in the answer to see if the item belongs to both category.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
select distinct(id_product) from TABLENAME
where id_category in (1,15)
```

Comment: This answer is not correct.  It will return `id_product = 2` (as well as the correct answer).  I can understand the answer, but not the upvote.

Comment: What am I missing here?  Where is returning of `id_product = 2` incorrect?  We're simply returning unique ids filtered by `id_category in (1,15)` per the question.

Comment: How can I use this inside a left join clause?